# How to continuously feed items from array into two stacks, the two stacks will then feed data into queue

Tags: java, eclipse

text file which contains a set of items like so: t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14,t15,t16,t17,t18

The two stacks and queue are limited to hold only 7 items each, I need to continuously keep feeding the items into stacks which will then go onto a queue.

Output for the stacks would be:

`Lift1 :t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7`
`Lift2 :t8,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14`

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {



         ECFile ecf = new ECFile();

         Stack<String> lift1 = new Stack<>();
         Stack<String> lift2 = new Stack<>();
         Queue<String> Conveyer = new LinkedList<>();
         BlockingQueue<String> bq1 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(7);


         String[] cargo = ecf.getArray("ConstructionData6.txt");
         ecf.displayArray(cargo,"");

         int food      = 0;
         int materials  = 0;
         int tools = 0;
         int other     = 0;

         bq1.offer("test");

         for (int k=0; k<cargo.length; k++)
          {

              switch(cargo[k].substring(0,1)) 
               {
                  case  "F" : food++;
                              break;         
                  case  "M" : materials++;
                              break;
                  case  "T" : tools++;
                              break;    
                  default   : other++;
                               break;
               }
          }

            System.out.println("\nFood    :  "+food);
            System.out.println("Materials : "+materials);
            System.out.println("Tools    : "+tools);
            System.out.println("Errors   : "+other + "\n");




            for(int k=0; k<cargo.length; k++) 
            {
                if(k < 7)
                {
                    lift1.push(cargo[k]);
                }
                else if(k < 14)
                {
                    lift2.push(cargo[k]);
                }



            }


            System.out.println("Lift Cargo: ");
            System.out.println("lift1: " +lift1); 
            System.out.println("lift2: " +lift2);


    }
```

My loop pushes the data into stacks but if there are more items than they can hold the items get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question:

You feed elements into two stacks that have maximum capacity of 7
any items that do not feed into the stacks they go into the queue.

```
for each item in cargo:
  can I put it in the first stack?
  else can I put in the second stack?
  else put in the queue.
```

here is some code pointers:

```
if (lift1.size() < MAX_SIZE) {
   lift1.push(cargo[k]);
else if (lift2.size() < MAX_SIZE) {
  ....
```

Edit: Based on the comment bellow.

So, you need to keep track if the stack is allowed to receive items. If the stack is in emptying state, you need to push items in the next stack, and if the second stack goes to emptying state, you move to the first stack.

you need a structure to keep the state of your stack (lift). You can create a wrapper class or have an array to keep the states.

e.g:

```
class Lift {
 int capacity;
 boolean emptying;
 Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

 public Lift(int maxCapacity) {
  this.capacity = maxCapacity;
  this.emptying = false;
 }


 public boolean push(String item) {
  if (!emptying && stack.size() < capacity) {
    stack.push(item);
    return true;
  } else {
     //state is emptying
     emptying = true;
     return false
  }
 }

 public void pushtoQueue(Queue queue) {
   while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
     queue.add(stack.pop();
   }
   emptying = false;
 }

}
```

and then you main loop is

```
boolean result1 = lift1.push(cargo[k]);
if (!result1) {
  lift2.push(cargo[k]);
}
```

Comment: The elements are fed into 2 stacks, once they are full one by one they feed elements into queue (queue feeds elements into 3 arrays later on) the elements wait for one stack to empty the items into queue and the elements are then fed into the first empty stack